# Update referencing another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, informix

I have a statement that needs writing (with generic names for stuff, since this is for work) to update a column 'updCol' in table 'tUpd'.  tUpd also has a column 'linkCol' which is present in another table tOther.  tOther has another column 'idCol'.

My problem is to update the updCol value of rows in tUpd which correspond via linkCol to rows with a given idCol value.

One solution I think should work is the following;

```
update
    tUpd
set
    updCol = XXX
where exists (
    select
        idCol
    from
        tOther
    where
        tOther.linkCol = tUpd.linkCol
    and tOther.idCol = MY_ID
)
```

However, I have worries that this approach will lead to poor performance, since I've been warned of sub-queries in relation to performance before - this sub-query will be run once for each row of tUpd, is this correct?

Has anyone got a better suggestion?

**Important Update**: my workplace avoids using SQL JOINs at all costs, preferring to join within the where clauses using, eg, `where a.col = b.col`.  This is arguably rather awkward but allows a flexibility in especially logging which I don't fully understand.  SO, I'm looking for non-JOIN-using solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simply like this

```
UPDATE DestinationTable
SET DestinationTable.UpdateColumn =  SourceTable.UpdateColumn 
FROM SourceTable
WHERE DestinationTable.JoinColumn = SourceTable.JoinColumn
```

Comment: So I don't need to include `DestinationTable` in the `FROM` part? Interesting.

Comment: So, what would be the best answer? :)

Comment: I've edited to set UpdateColumn to `XXX`, but it still needs an extra part to the WHERE to check SourceTable's, for example, `IDColumn` as stated in the original question.  At the moment, it's still the other answer :)

Comment: I have just given a general idea!

Comment: You've convinced me lol, I'm pretty new on SO, wasn't so sure which is better, a specific answer to the question or a general solution to the type of problem.  I'll go with the latter.

Comment: Even though the official documentation indicate this solution (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_246.htm), it doesn't seem to work .... The solution of Dipesh Shah is the only one working for me ....

Comment: This does not work for me in our install of v12.10.  I'm not sure why.  Prefer this solution instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18612728/12601

Answer (score 7):

All the above solutions gives an error in Informix as it cannot find the one of the table.
Here is a solution for this which worked for me:

```
update table1
set table1.field2 = (select table2.field2 from table2 where table1.field1 = table2.field1)
where table1.field1 in (select table2.field1 from table2)
```

---

edit: A multi-column solution from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701344/informix-update-with-select-syntax)

```
update table1
set (table1.field2, table2.field3) = (
  (select table2.field2, table2.field3 
     from table2 
     where table1.field1 = table2.field1)
)
where table1.field1 in (select table2.field1 from table2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help you

```
update tUpd
set tU.updCol = XXX
from tOther tot, tUpd tU   
where tot.linkCol = tU.linkCol
  and tot.idCol = MY_ID
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938270/update-informix-table-with-joins) is link to similar problem.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it sets the value of the updCol column to the id, which isn't the desired effect (I just want to set that to a pre-defined value), this looks like the right kind of thing.  I wasn't aware I could use `FROM` within an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: I edited the post. Now Value XXX will change column updCol. Is it ok ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm), `UPDATE` statement doesn't support `FROM` clause in Informix.

Answer (score 1):

This works for Informix Databases:

```
UPDATE dest_table V 
SET field_1 = 
   (SELECT field_1 FROM source_tbl WHERE field_2 IS NULL
   AND field_1 = V.field_1);
```

[Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1830.htm)