# How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix

I'm trying to do an update using data from another table. I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612728/1476885) (the second part), but it is not working for me. I'm receiving a generic error message of syntax error.

I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12493901/1476885) and received a syntax error message too.

If I try to update just one column, it works:

```
UPDATE dogs
SET name = 
    (
        SELECT 'Buddy'
        FROM systables 
        WHERE tabid = 1
     );
```

But I need to update multiples columns. Unfortunately, this is not working:

```
UPDATE dogs
SET (name, breed) = 
    (
        SELECT 'Buddy', 'pug'
        FROM systables 
        WHERE tabid = 1
    );
```

<sup>Informix version is 12.10.FC8</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing 1 more set of parentheses around the subquery.
From the [Informix manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1265.htm):

> The subquery must be enclosed between parentheses. These parentheses
>   are nested within the parentheses that immediately follow the equal (
>   = ) sign. If the expression list includes multiple subqueries, each subquery must be enclosed between parentheses, with a comma ( , )
>   separating successive subqueries:
>
> ```
> UPDATE ... SET ... = ((subqueryA),(subqueryB), ... (subqueryN))
> ```
>
> The following examples show the use of subqueries in the SET clause:
>
> ```
> UPDATE items    
> SET (stock_num, manu_code, quantity) = 
>   ( 
>     (
>       SELECT stock_num, manu_code 
>        FROM stock     
>        WHERE description = 'baseball'
>     ),
>     2
>   )    
> WHERE item_num = 1 AND order_num = 1001;
>
> UPDATE table1    
> SET (col1, col2, col3) =
>   (
>     (
>       SELECT MIN (ship_charge), MAX (ship_charge) 
>       FROM orders
>     ),
>     '07/01/2007'
>   )
> WHERE col4 = 1001;
> ```

So in order for your update to be accepted by Informix it has to be:

```
UPDATE dogs
SET (name, breed) = 
  (
    (
      SELECT 'Buddy', 'pug'
      FROM systables 
      WHERE tabid = 1
    )
  );
```