# Using subquery in an update always requires subquery in a where clause?

Tags: sql, informix

This is a common SQL query for me:

```
update table1 set col1 = (select col1 from table2 where table1.ID = table2.ID)
where exists (select 1 from table2 where table1.ID = table2.ID)
```

Is there any way to avoid having two nearly identical subqueries? This query is an obvious simplification but performance suffers and query is needlessly messy to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Informix don't support the FROM clause at UPDATE statement.
The way to workaround and you will get better results (performance) is change the UPDATE to MERGE statement.

This will work only if your database is version 11.50 or above

```
MERGE INTO table1 as t1
USING table2 as t2
   ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set (t1.col1, t1.col2) = (t2.col1, t2.col2);
```

Check [IBM Informix manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/index.jsp?tab=search&searchWord=merge) for more information

Comment: Hi @Filipe, this isn't exclusive of Informix, oracle and SqlServer support this statement too. Check the syntax and you will discover you can work with insert+update or insert+delete at the same statement.

Comment: So, I did some testing and reading. It appears that SQL optimizer always reads table2 using sequential scan. I have made several tests confirming that. This is ofc terrible news if I want to merge just a small fragment of table2. However, I can supply temporary table instead of real table like this: MERGE INTO table1 as t1 USING (select * from table2 where col1 > 50) ON t1.ID = t2.ID WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set t1.Col1 = t2.Col1. This is fast, tested on table2 which is about 6M rows.

Comment: well.. about the sequencial scan, check if have the indexes to attend the join/filter and if exists medium/high statistics updated . Anyway, your solution (the sub-query) is a acceptable solution for the performance problem. (but the sequencial scan, is something what I do not consider correct if your schema/statistics still correct, so.. maybe open a PMR at IBM support to check could be necessary).

Comment: I've found article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1102informixmerge/ where they explicitly say that sequential scan is done on the source table. It's in the chapter Understanding the internal processing. Looks like it's by design, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Update with inner join can be used to avoid subqueries

something like this:

```
update t1 
set col1 = t2.col1
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: Try it with alias t1 on table1 in the from clause.  I edited the answer.

Comment: No change. Just to clarify that I'm using Informix database in case you missed the tag. Thanks.

Comment: I saw the tag.  Felipe probably has the correct answer.  The syntax in this example, which uses aliases, is valid for redbrick and sql server.  It would appear that with Informix, you have to use table names.

Comment: Felipe just deleted his answer which was interesting to say the least. Unfortunately the documentation indicated that works just for Extended Parallel Server which is unavailable to me and is rarely used. I have Informix 11.70 which is latest version but different product.

Comment: No. My answer wasn't correct either. i searched around and this isn't valid for all versions of informix. See this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10999495/1385896. I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks anyway. The problem that I'm facing is that table2 grows by 150M+/year of rows for six years now. The join is done with nine columns. Harsh environment for a developer.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 update table1 set col1 = (select col1 as newcol from table2 where table1.ID = table2.ID)
where exists (newcol)
```