# update sql query using joins informix

Tags: sql-update, inner-join, informix

I have one table table1 (id, name, surname, ssn) and a view1 (id, ssn) and here is my update clause

```
update table1 set 
ssn=v.ssn
from table1 t,view v 
where t.id=v.id
```

However I get syntax error  sql code -201, does anybody knows what is the problem?

Comment: There's a syntax error.  AFAIK, that syntax is not supported by Informix.  See the syntax diagram for the [UPDATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) statement at the IBM web site.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try:

```
UPDATE table1 SET ssn=(SELECT ssn FROM view WHERE table1.id=view.id)
```

PS You use strange names: `table1`, `view`. They say nothing about data in those tables/views. I hope this is only for this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MERGE statement.
But this depends the version of the Informix engine are you working (needs version 11.50 for this answer work).

Check this other similar question/answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027289/469192) for more information.

```
MERGE INTO table1 as t1
USING table2 as t2
   ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set (t1.col1, t1.col2) = (t2.col1, t2.col2);
```