# Update statement with Join in Informix

Tags: informix, sql-update

I need to select an employee_id from a table

```
select emp_id 
from employee emp, temp_data td where lower(td.supervisor_name) like lower(emp.last_name||emp.firstname)
```

and insert it into a field in the same table

```
update emp set emp.supervisor_id = **The value returned from the previous query**
from employee as emp
Inner join temp_table as td
on td.emp_id = emp.emp_id
```

Is there any way that I can achieve it? The problem is that I am referring to another field of the same table while setting it in the update statement.. Please let me know if there is any other route I could go... I am doing it in Informix.

Comment: Put the query in your update statement after Equlas to Symbol

Comment: Thanks for the reply... It is taking forever and gives me the following error... 

18:18:39  [UPDATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -79716, SQL State: IX000]  System or internal error java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]


I know there is something wrong in it because it's like declaring the same tables twice.. If you think it would work, can you  please write the whole statement for me..

Thanks

Comment: check this if this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004605/using-subquery-in-an-update-always-requires-subquery-in-a-where-clause/19027289#19027289  help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi ceinmart, thanks for the reply. But I am already using this query in a merge statement. I am not sure how efficient is using a merge inside another merge statement. Also, Its not just a simple assignment to do  ON t1.ID = t2.ID... It should be t1.id = select id from the table where last name matches... 


Is there a way to get the value first, store it in a variable and then update? that would be a lot easier...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your data 
done following check

table : temp_data table has following data

```
supervisor_name
------------------------------
kaushal
abc
solanki
def
```

table : employee table has following values

```
firstname  last_name
------------------------------
ajay       jadeja 
sachin     solanki 
kaushal    kumar
manish     galav
```

1.

```
 select  supervisor_name from temp_data 
 select  firstname from employee
```

Note the result
 1 record named kaushal which is match . So you need to update the the ID of kaushal

2.

```
   select  supervisor_name from temp_data 
   select  last_name from employee
```

1 record named solanki matches. So you need to update the the ID of solanki

see the result

Note how many rows you need to update (here 2)

First try your select query put into update query 
then you said it gaves error ..

then Try this :

Modified your select query as below and put it into your update query.

```
select emp_id 
from employee emp, temp_data td 
where 
( lower(td.supervisor_name) like lower(emp.last_name ) 
or 
lower(td.supervisor_name) like (emp.firstname) )
)
```

see the result 2 rows update or not ...????????

Comment: Woww..thanks for taking time to reply. I REALLY appreciate it. 

My issue is that the two querirs I have specified works fine individually. I am just confused how to make two declarations for each of the two tables in both queries...
see the bold

`update emp set emp.supervisor_id = select emp_id from **employee emp, temp_data td**

from ** employee as emp**
Inner join **temp_table as td**`

Answer (score 0):

Try this also it successfully update your data.

MERGE INTO employee as emp
USING temp_data as td
ON emp.emp_id = td.emp_id
   and ( lower(td.supervisor_name) like lower(emp.last_name) 
         or 
         lower(td.supervisor_name) like lower(emp.firstname) )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set emp.supervisor_id  = emp.emp_id